# 07' Dodge Durango Brake Lights Dont Work

Tags: dodge, tail-lights, durango

I have changed the brake light switch and checked all the fuses. They work when I turn on the headlights and I have recently had the rear bumper replaced do to an accident but the repair shop told me it was due to the brake light switch being the reason my brake lights don't work.

Comment: Have you checked or replaced the bulbs?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Hi, I don't get it. Do they work, or don't? Do you mean that they are on when you turn on the headlights but they won't turn off? At least in my Chevy the brake light switch is a "Dead man trigger" style. You need to make sure that when the pedal is depressed the switch is pressed. Then when you press the brake pedal the switch will go on.